# Highcharts for salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I need to implement 'Synchronized charts' in my Visualforce page (to display in portal). I found one which looks similar to my requirement in Highcharts. I analysed and tried to implement the same as POC.  When i tried to download, i found an option for free trail which is not working.

Please guide me if anyone faced similar issues with Highcharts or suggest some good option to get it done.

Ref URL: https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts

Thanks you

Prag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL you tried is no longer exists. Please try with this URL `http://www.highcharts.com/download`.

Instead of downloading you can use their CDN to reference it like `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com"></script>` directly in your Visualforce as you usually do with JQuery.